# TypeAhead doesn't show query results

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, bootstrap-typeahead

i'm very desperate!

i have this problem with Bootstrap Typeahead.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">Recipients</label>
    <input id="recipients" name="recipients" 
        autocomplete="off" 
        class="form-control" 
        data-role="tagsinput">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$('#recipientsContainer').tagsinput({
            allowDuplicates: false,
            trimValue: true,
            confirmKeys: [13, 44],
            typeahead: {
                hint: true,
                highlight: true,
                minLength: 4,
                limit: 10,
                source: function (query) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/app/route",
                        type: 'POST',
                        dataType: 'JSON',
                        data: {'query' : query},
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                            return(data);
                        }
                    });
                },
                afterSelect: function() {
                    this.$element[0].value = '';
                }
            }
        });
```

**After Ajax call I get this array in consolle:**

```
["Justin Demetria +393281893574", "Dylan Alea +393700488191", "Zahir Tatyana +393007841301", "Ryan Veda +393542236060", "Hunter Wanda +393393156943"]
```

The problem is: I see nothing :( nothing appears. typeahead doesn't work.

In the console, I get this error

```
bootstrap-tagsinput.js Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined.
```

How can I fix it?

I'm using Bootstrap 3, last Typeahead js source.

Answer (score 1):

James, now my ajax call is:

```
$('#recipientsContainer').tagsinput({
            allowDuplicates: false,
            trimValue: true,
            confirmKeys: [13, 44],
            typeahead: {
                source: function(queryForHints) {
                    if (queryForHints.length < 4)
                        return '';
                    var parameters = {'queryForHints': queryForHints};
                    jQuery.ajax({
                        url: "/app/route",
                        data: parameters,
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function(data) {
                            var sourceData = [];
                            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                                sourceData.push(data[i].text);
                            }
                            return (sourceData);
                        },
                        error: function(data) {
                            console.log("error for xxxxx/xxxxx");
                        },
                        async: true
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

But the error persist:

```
bootstrap-tagsinput.js:331 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'success' of undefined
```

the error is on bootstrap-tagsinput.js row 331, and i find:

```
if ($.isFunction(data.success)) {
              // support for Angular callbacks
              data.success(processItems);
```

Can we fix the problem ?

in my humble opinion, the problem is that input - tags can not understand the SUCCESS of an ajax call

Answer (score 0):

For typeahead use Bloodhound to get your data not ajax.

Your code should look like something like this:

```
var customers = new Bloodhound({
            datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
            queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
            remote: {
                url: '/api/customers?query=%QUERY',
                wildcard: '%QUERY'
            }
        });

        $('#customer').typeahead({
            minLength: 3,
            highlight: true
        }, {
            name: 'customers',
            display: 'name',
            source: customers
        }).on("typeahead:select", function(e, customer) {
            vm.customerId = customer.id;
        });
```

For more Information on Bloodhound:
[Bloodhound@github](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/bloodhound.md)

And here some examples for typeahead: [TypeAhead Examples](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/)

Comment: i read all of your code, but i don't understand how can i use it in my typehead function usen inside an tagsinput function (like my code)..can you provide me more help? Many thanks..

Comment: you dont have to use the tagsinput function, just use the typeahead function like seen in my code and specify the behavior like its documented in the api.

Comment: if i put your code in my page, for ex, i receive this error: bloodhound is not defined

Comment: oh my fault... for this kind of typeahead you need to install the twitter-typeahead Nuget-package that its running correctly

Comment: oh :( another components that i don't know :( if i find it can you help me to make it works with my needs?

Comment: ok, i add typeahead bundle and now bloodhound fn is recognized! now in consolle i get "Uncaught Error: missing source"

Comment: Yggras pleae help me, i'm in a hurry